# spring security configuration for jax-rs RESTfull services

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, spring-security

I have some **JAX-RS** **RESTfull** application with Spring(JDBC,injections and AOP).
I am trying to configure my application with Spring Security (authorization/authentication and users management).
Have you any examples with good explanations how to config Spring Security with **JAX-RS**?
Sorry for my poor english...
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check the following article on the topic :

[Configuring Spring Security for a RESTful Web Services](http://www.networkedassets.com/configuring-spring-security-for-a-restful-web-services/)

Comment: good example...but may be you have more examples to secure application independently by Spring Security?